# Is there a term for something that is thought of in one way, then something happens and it's suddenly thought of in a new way?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, nouns, idiom-requests

I’m writing a business growth strategy book based on weeds. Weeds are thought of as essentially living garbage, as pests, as useless. But they are actually miracles of strategy, resilience and execution. I believe my book will cause many to see weeds in a whole new way, and I’d like to use the term, if there is one, to describe them. The closest I’ve found is neologism, which can mean the introduction of new meanings to existing words.

Answer (score 1):

You want people to see *weeds* in a different light. I do not know how *neologism* fits there; you are just taking up a commonplace entity and trying to breathe new perspective and meaning into it. Sounds cool!

Anyway, I suggest you go with *perspective* as in *Weeds: A fresh perspective* or perhaps *approach* as in *Weeds: A different approach.*

And both these words are nouns, to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Reevaluate. Reassess. See it in a new light.

Comment: Thank you, those are close, but I'm looking for a noun. What is something like this called?

Answer (score 0):

Serendipity is the occurrence and development by chance in a happy or beneficial way.

This captures some, but not all, of the meaning you are searching for.  It doesn't address the aspect of looking at something in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

## How about "paradigm shift"?

> Paradigm shift—a time/situation when the usual and accepted way of doing or thinking about something changes completely
>
> — [CED](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/paradigm-shift)

An example from [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/paradigm-shift.asp):

> The internet created a paradigm shift in the way business is conducted.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your consideration and help. We didn't find a word that fits this precisely, but found some workarounds.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for the replies here. I found one word, transmogrify, which means to transform in a surprising or magical manner. That fits pretty nicely as a verb. But perhaps it's time to create a new word to describe the transformed object. My best candidate:  Ampliomorph. Amplio is to improve, increase or enhance, Morph is, of course, to change or transform. An ampliomorph would be something which has been transformed into something greater than its former form.

Comment: However it conveys the idea of something that has actually changed. In your example though weed is still the same, it's only the perception or understanding of it that has changed.